# How to display java variable value in HTML input Textbox by click input button in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

**Here is my JSP Code**

```
<%@page import="PresentationPkg.TestCls"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="ex.jsp"> 
      <input  type="text" id="resultCode" name="resultCode">
      <input  type="button" name="viewValue" value="Submit View"/>
      <%
        String newTestResultCode = TestCls.getMaxTestResultID();
      %>
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to show variable 'newTestResultCode' value in 'resultCode' textBox by clicking button 'Submit View'

Comment: Simply use `value="<%=newTestResultCode %>"` inside your textbox.

Comment: @Swati this time that underlined as red. error is cant find symbol

Comment: Put that jsp code where you are getting value inside variable before your inputs .

Comment: Yes. That the issue. now i corrected that. now working correctly.Thanks Swati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below Code. Do not forget to add jquery js

> < script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></ script>

Copy paste below code and run it.

```
<%@page import="PresentationPkg.TestCls"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <%
    String newTestResultCode = TestCls.getMaxTestResultID();
  %>
    <form action="ex.jsp"> 
  <input  type="text" id="resultCode" name="resultCode">
  <input  id="myButton" type="button" name="viewValue" value="Submit View" />

  </form>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myButton').click(function (){
           $("#resultCode").val("<%=newTestResultCode%>");
        });
    });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also download jquery js in your project and use it. The js function will set your variable data into input box.

Comment: Because you wanted it to reflect using onclick method. You can use javascript function for it. I prefered jquery. you can use plain javascript instead of it.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Why-do-we-use-jQuery-over-JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<input  type="text" id="resultCode" name="resultCode" value=<%=newTestResultCode%>>
```

Comment: this time that underlined as red. error is cant find symbol

Comment: That is because you didn't instantiate you variable before calling it. You can replace variable name in value property with TestCls.getMaxTestResultID() and that should do the trick

Comment: Yes. That the issue. now i corrected that. now working correctly.Thanks @admi